# How do I remove or hide the green triangles from the corner of the cell when numbers are formatted as text in Excel for Mac?

Tags: macos, ms-office

It is amazing how distracting these green triangles can be when trying to read the content of a spreadsheet with many numeric values stored as text to prevent them from being displayed with scientific notation, and a wide variety of other side effects such as truncating leading zeroes.  I have a spreadsheet that I need to read carefully which was littered with these green triangles, and need to remove them because in this case, they are not adding value or being helpful.

Answer (score 3):

From the top menu, choose **Excel**, **Preferences**.  Under the heading **Formulas and Lists**, choose **Error Checking**.  Uncheck the box next to **Numbers formatted as text**.

Another way to get there if your spreadsheet is presently displaying errors is from the top menu by choosing **Tools**, **Error Checking...**, followed by pressing the **Options** button.

This second menu item also causes error checking to take place first, and if no errors are found, the configuration panel will not open.  Instead, a message will be displayed that indicates error checking being complete.